# Concatenation In "As" Statement

Tags: mysql

A newbie but can a concatenation occur with an "as" statement?

Ex.

```
Set @nthpct:=75; 
select 
-code- as concat(@nthpct,' percent') 
from widget;
```

Comment: `as` introduces an alias.  This doesn't make sense as is.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is not supported by MySQL.

A column alias needs to be a literal string. You cannot use a variable in the column alias name.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but the AS goes after the function, not before.

```
Set @nthpct:=75; 
select concat(@nthpct,' percent') as code
from widget;
```

Comment: At that point, though, what are you selecting from `widget`?  I was under the impression that `-code-` was some complex expression that wouldn't be suitable after `as` either.

Comment: That was my impression too. This is about creating dynamic column aliases

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do what you are attempting as dynamic column names.  However, you SHOULD be able to do it by using DynamicSQL where you BUILD the string you want to execute, thus building your string with the column names as you want.  Then, prepare the command and execute it.